# Is assigning new properties to built-in types actually illegal?

Tags: javascript

I had the following code that used to work fine in Chrome but has suddenly stopped working in the latest version (38.0.2125.104).

```js
(function() {
    "use strict";
    
    var stringPrototype = String.prototype;
    stringPrototype.foo = function() { this.$foo = 1234; };
    var s = "abcd";
    s.foo();
})();
```

Now I get the error (if you run the snippet, you'll see the error in the console):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '$foo' of abcd

I am interested to know if this is a new bug in Chrome or if what I had been doing is actually illegal.  If it is illegal, is there any reference specification that would describe why this is so?

This has never caused an error in previous versions of Chrome.

Comment: Even if it didn't throw an error, `"abcd"` is **not** a String instance - it's a string primitive. The expression `s.foo()` implicitly creates a wrapper String instance around the primitive. The addition of the property would therefore have no real effect. I wonder if Chrome is instantiating the wrapper objects as frozen?

Comment: @Pointy, thanks for the insight!  You are right, my previous (supposedly working) code was not actually accomplishing anything at all.  The property was not sticking (for the reason you mentioned).  So in practice, my problem is solved, since my setting of that value was useless I can remove that entirely, for better or worse.

Comment: @Pointy - In non-strict mode `this` is always an object (an instance of String).

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, I don't fully understand why the error is being thrown, but `this` will refer to the **temporary** String wrapper created around the primitive. Once the function returns and the statement is finished, the wrapper will be garbage collected. You can't add properties to a string primitive.

Comment: @Pointy - Of course string primitives can't have properties. I was saying that just to explain why it might have worked before.

Comment: @Derek, it didn't throw an *error* before, but I just tested it without `"use strict;"` in the old version of Chrome and the value was not preserved on the original `s` variable.  (Not contradicting either of you, just trying to paint a fuller picture)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 yes, maybe; it's weird that the runtime would treat the temporary object as not being receptive to new properties, however you roll it.

Comment: @KirkWoll - The value should not be preserved unless you explicitly wrap the primitive in String `var s = new String("abcd")`, then the value will be preserved.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, thanks!  I hadn't considered that option.

Comment: FWIW, the error is not reported if not in strict mode.

Answer (score 1):

The comments above helped me solve my problem.  To sum up, the assignment I was making:

```
this.$foo = 1234
```

Was *never* doing anything.  In the newer version of Chrome this spurious assignment actually results in an error.  This seems like an improvement since it causes a failure sooner and should surface a potential bug earlier.

Thus, though I thought the newer version of Chrome was causing an error in previously working code, since my code had not ever been doing anything, I can safely remove the assignment, since the behavior must will be exactly the same.

(Answering this as a community wiki since all the heavy lifting was done by Pointy and Derek.)